# Javascript Elevator Program

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating an elevator in HTML/CSS/Javascript and running into an issue in some parts of the javascript.

I am trying to log each button pressed, to then have the elevator go to each floor in order. I'm currently adding each each floor to an array.

Everytime I run the program the elevator runs through the entire array for each iteration.

How can I add each floor to the array, and then one the floor has been visited, it gets removed and the program keeps moving through the existing array?

#### JavaScript

```
var Elevator = (function Elevator() {

  var floors = 10,
  origin = 1,
  queue = [],
  current, 
  isMoving = false,
  destination;
  
  

  
  // this gets the floor being click
  // and assigns the value of destination to the new floor
  function getFloors(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    destination = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(destination);
    if (destination !== origin){
     isMoving = true;
     queue.push(destination);
     console.log(queue);
   }
 }

 function moveFloors(destination){
 }

  // this acts as a controller
  // for all events and how and what we bind them to
  function bindEvents() {
    $('.btn').on('click', getFloors);
  }
  // this runs the bind events
  // and only runs the bind events
  function init(){
    bindEvents();
  }
  // this makes the init method public for invoking
  return {
    init: init()
  };
})();

Elevator.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish but since you're using jQuery and you want to iterate all floors you can use the [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.
e.g. `$(floors).each(function() {
  // do something
};`

Oh, and by the way, I see you used push, you can use `pop()` to extract the first object in that array.

Comment: `.pop()` actually takes the last element, not the first, that would be `.unshift()`, though `pop` would probably make more sense indeed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: Indeed it pops the last index: https://jsfiddle.net/4hcffge3/
I was confused with a stack :)

Answer (score 0):

This just screams "State Machine" to me, so I highly recommend you read at least some of [this article](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).

But, for your problem at hand, you're going to need to do some work when the elevator stops moving. I see you have an `isMoving` flag, so when that gets set to false, [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) the floor you have reached from the `queue` and begin moving to the next destination in the array.

Repeat until the `queue` array is empty.

Comment: could I also use `shift` to cut off the first item of the array? 

Also - the way its been set up it adds to the array each time, which forces the animation to trigger on each click. Womp.

Comment: Yeah, `shift` would work fine too. You probably just want an if-check to determine whether the animation should trigger. `if (isMoving) // add to queue, but don't animate; else //begin animation;`

Answer (score 0):

You could define your elevator like this

```
var Elevator = (function Elevator() {

  var floors = 10,
  queue = [],
  current = 1, 
  isMoving = false,
  destination;

  // This gets the floor being clicked and adds it to the queue
  // if the elevator is stationary and the floor is not the current floor,
  // or if the elevator is in motion and the floor is not the most recently requested floor.
  // It also sets the elevator in motion if a floor was added to the queue.
  function getFloors(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    destination = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(destination);
    var repeatedFloor = isMoving ? queue[queue.length - 1] : current;
    if (destination !== repeatedFloor){
      queue.push(destination);
      if (!isMoving) {
        isMoving = true;
        setTimeout(moveFloors, 3000);
      }
      console.log(queue);
    }
  }

  // This completes a move for the elevator (sets the current floor)
  // and either halts the elevator or continues its motion to the
  // next floor in the queue.
  function moveFloors() { 
    console.log(queue);
    current = queue.shift();
    console.log("moved to floor " + current);
    if (queue[0] !== undefined) {
      setTimeout(moveFloors, 3000);
    } else {
      isMoving = false;
    }
  }

  // this acts as a controller
  // for all events and how and what we bind them to
  function bindEvents() {
    $('.btn').on('click', getFloors);
  }
  // this runs the bind events
  // and only runs the bind events
  function init(){
    bindEvents();
  }
  // this makes the init method public for invoking
  return {
    init: init()
  };
})();
```

The `getFloors` method handles the logic of determining whether or not to add the floor to the queue, and starts the elevator moving if it wasn't before and now needs to (using `setTimeout` - you may have some other kind of trigger). The `moveFloors` method updates the current floor and either halts the elevator motion or sets it off to the next floor, depending on the state of the queue. This solution uses `shift` to pull floors off the front of the queue.

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGzJwE?editors=101

I'm sure this could use a lot of cleanup and you may need to modify it to fit your particular situation, but hopefully it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use some more advanced data structure that allows easier adding and dropping of elements. If that is your struggle (?) :)

Potentially some linked List